# Golang Gin: Middleware with CORS not working

Tags: http, go, cors, middleware, go-gin

I've got a POST request from my frontend app to my backend app written in Go using Gin. I was getting an error saying:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

so that pointed me to implement CORS in my backend app. So I did by using `"github.com/gin-contrib/cors"`:

`web.go`:

```
func NewApp() *App {

    db := SetUpDB()
    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        //AllowOrigins:    []string{"http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"},
        AllowMethods:    []string{"PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS","DELETE"},
        AllowHeaders:    []string{"Origin"},
        AllowAllOrigins: true,
        //ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    }))

    return &App{
        Db:     db,
        Router: router,
    }
}
```

and in `main.go` I've got:

```
app := core.NewApp()

    //app.Router.Use(CORS())

    defer func() {
        app.Db.Close()
        log.Printf("core: database stopping")
    }()

    app.Router.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("db", app.Db)
    })

    app.Router.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "welcome TEST"})
    })

    // Initialize all api routes
    routes.InitializeRoutes(app.Router.Group("/api/v1"))
```

as you can see I only set `PUT` in `AllowMethods` with the intention of testing CORS was actually working. By allowing only `PUT` I was expecting no methods other than `PUT` were allowed but I was wrong. I've performed a `GET` request from my frontend app and it goes through (it returns data), this leads me to think than the CORS implementation is not being picked up.

While browsing around, I've found people not using the package `"github.com/gin-contrib/cors"` but creating their own middleware:

```
func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        fmt.Println(c.Request.Header)
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, Origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        //c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

and then:

```
func NewApp() *App {

    db := SetUpDB()
    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(CORS())

    return &App{
        Db:     db,
        Router: router,
    }
}
```

I tried this as well with no luck. Same results are coming back.

Furthermore, when I perform the `GET` and print the method in my backend (`c.Request.Method`) the result is `GET`. But when I perform a `POST` and print the method I'm getting `OPTIONS`

What am I missing? Why `router` is not using the provided middleware?

Comment: You never need to allow `Origin` as a request header.

Answer (score 3):

There are two pieces to this question:

1. The first one was indicated above by Heiko: Get is a simple request so the result is always gonna be returned for these kind of requests.
2. Now, after testing back my `POST`, I was still getting errors. I had checked over and over the CORS config, changing things here and there just to find out that the routes for Category were define such as:

```
categoryRouter.POST("/", controllers.CreateNewCategory)
categoryRouter.GET("/", controllers.ListAllCategories)
```

as you can see there is a trailing `/` which was causing my request to be redirected and an error to be returned since the url used for the request was `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/categories`. I updated the routes to be:

```
categoryRouter.POST("", controllers.CreateNewCategory)
categoryRouter.GET("", controllers.ListAllCategories)
```

and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header is only checked for CORS requests that *cannot* result from a Javascript-less HTML page (so-called non-simple requests). For simple requests such as GET with only standard headers, only the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is checked and the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header plays no role.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, good to know. Base on the code above, you have any indication about why my POSTs are not working? When I perform the GET and print the method in my backend (`c.Request.Method`) the result is `GET`. But when I perform the POST and print the method I'm getting `OPTIONS`

Comment: Non-simple requests are made only after a succesful _preflight_ request, which is an OPTIONS request.